# Check if DOM is in stable condition (no active reflows/repaints) after JavaScript execution

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

**Preface**

*Please note that word **stable** in question below does not refer to some specific coined industry term (I work with js for last 5 years and haven't heard of term "stable DOM" so assume that there is no such thing). Also this doesn't refer to specification. Stable means - no reflows or repaints are being done at the moment and no scheduled.*

**Question**

How to check if DOM tree / page is **stable** after some javascript that triggers repaint/reflow ([see here for examples of reflow/repaint](https://sites.google.com/site/getsnippet/javascript/dom/repaints-and-reflows-manipulating-the-dom-responsibly) )

1. Is there some (`browser`, `window`, `DOM` etc.) event I can `addEventListener` to?
2. Maybe there is some strange way to do this like putting my code I need to run as a callback function to some function like `requestAnimationFrame()`?

**My set up** (I believe the question is enough detailed with only text above, but people asked for my set up)

I have React application. In one place I am using `.offsetTop` recursively to find offset of the few components from the page body in `componentDidMount` method. Namely with this function, where I pass 4 elements found by `document.getElementById()`

```
findPosY = obj => {
    let curtop = 0
    if (typeof obj.offsetParent !== 'undefined' && obj.offsetParent) {
      while (obj.offsetParent) {
        curtop += obj.offsetTop
        obj = obj.offsetParent
      }
      curtop += obj.offsetTop
    } else if (obj.y) {
      curtop += obj.y
    }
    return curtop
  }
```

This function return for 2 of those elements the same height. But if I do calculations after `100ms` everything works perfectly.

In other component I'm doing some interaction using js with inline styles of rendered html that can happen during rendering.

**UPDATE 1.** `DOMContentLoaded` won't aid here. Running height calculation as

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // call appropriate function
})
```

doesn't provide desired result.

Comment: When are you doing the repaint? on load? or on interaction? please add more details to the question. By stable do you mean when the repaint is done?

Comment: If it doesn't refer to some specific term, then what exactly _do_ you mean by "stable"?

Comment: Repainting doesn't happen until your Javascript returns to the event loop.

Comment: @Huangism updated question. Adrian - stable means no repaint and reflows happening, so I can measure height of some elements.

Comment: If your code runs onload then I would say by the time that window has loaded then you should be good to go

Comment: maybe `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {...`

Comment: `The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.` @johnSmith so rather no, as I'm having React application / SPA and this event should be fired when my slim `index.html` is downloaded and parsed.

Comment: check the part about html5 parsing https://molily.de/domcontentloaded/

Comment: @johnSmith https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-end this is cleared for me. but thanks for hint. checking if this will work

Comment: @johnSmith it failed to work. updating question with this info

Comment: site not found error for  (see here for examples of reflow/repaint ) https://sites.google.com/site/getsnippet/javascript/dom/repaints-and-reflows-manipulating-the-dom-responsibly , please readd the link.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any such thing.

If there's any "reflow scheduled", `offsetTop` must stop until the reflow is done and only return a value once "in stable condition", so I'm not sure how such a thing would help you even if it existed.

Check what leads to the differences you're observing between an immediate and a delayed execution. If that doesn't help, create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), maybe it'll turn into a useful bug report for the browser you're testing with.